# Zero velocity and non-zero average acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Can you have a zero velocity and nonzero *average* acceleration?

I am confused with the word "average" here. If the question would be, "Can you have a zero velocity and nonzero acceleration?" my answer would be yes. An example would be a ball thrown upward. At the highest point, the velocity is zero and instantaneous acceleration is -9.8 m/s$^2$. Since the question states that *average* acceleration, I can't think of an example that would satisfy the question.

Comment: If the acceleration is constant the average acceleration is equal to that constant. You've answered your own question. Now, are you asking about a *constant* zero velocity or an *instantaneous* zero velocity?

Comment: As you say, it doesn't make sense to compare a time-averaged quantity to an instantaneous quantity. The question could be "in a given time interval, is it possible to have zero velocity at some point in the interval, while the average acceleration over this interval is zero?" or "in a given time interval, can the average velocity over that interval be zero while the average acceleration over the interval is nonzero?"

Answer (score 1):

> Can you have a zero velocity and nonzero average acceleration?

- If you by *velocity* mean *instantaneous* velocity, then the question makes no sence. The corresponding acceleration will as well be instantaneous (and the answer would be **yes**.)
  $$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}a_{av}=a_{inst}$$

  - ... unless it is not a requirement that the acceleration is averaged over the same timespan as the velocity is measured. Then the answer is **yes**, and an upwards thrown stone is an example (it reaches a halt of $v=0$ and starts falling down, but the acceleration is at all times equal to the gravitational acceleration $-g$, so the average acceleration is as well, $a_{av}=-g$.)
- If you mean *average* velocity, then the answer is **no**. Average acceleration doesn't take into account what happen in between; only the end points are interesting:
  $$a_{av}=\frac{v_2-v_1}{\Delta t}$$
  If average acceleration is non-zero, then $v_1 \neq v_2$ and the average of these is surely non-zero as well.