# Non zero accetion, varying speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Can an object have non zero acceleration without having varying speed? How? Can you explain with an example please.?

Comment: What thoughts have you on the subject?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165361/zero-velocity-and-non-zero-average-acceleration?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because acceleration also includes change in direction. For example, a race car on the track goes in a circle. If its speed is 150 mph for the entire race, it is still accelerating because it is not going in a straight line.